# C#: Using regular expression (Regex) to duplicate a specific character in a string

Tags: c#, regex, character

Anyone know how to use regex to duplicate a specific character in a string?

I have a path that is entered like this:

```
C:/Example/example
```

I would like to use regex (or any other method) to display it like this:

> C://Example//example

Is it possible?

This is where I'm getting the file path

```
private void btnSearchImage_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

        ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp"; 

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string filenName = ofd.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(filenName);
            string path = filenName;
            txtimgPath.Text = path;

        }


    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this? Seems like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Comment: @tmw I'm doing that cause when I insert the path into a MySql database with a single slash it automatically removes that slash for unknown reason but when I insert another slash it will ignore it. And no this is a problem not verifying a solution ...

Comment: You're not getting my point. Why do you feel it's necessary to add an additional `/`?

Comment: I just told you in the previous comment.. if I insert the path as normal in the database it gets displayed like this for example: C:Exampleexample instead of C:\Example\example.. adding another slash will make it normal..

Comment: Aha. Can you show how you're inserting it into the database?

Answer (score 2):

How about this without RegEx?

```
var text = "C:/Example/example";

string outputValue = text.Replace("/","//"); //returns "C://Example//example"
```

Comment: it's not working. Please see the edited post I'm implementing your suggested code after the line where I set string path = fileName; witht this code: path.Replace("/", "//");

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
private void btnSearchImage_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    ofd.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp)|*.jpg; *.jpeg; *.gif; *.bmp"; 

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string filenName = ofd.FileName;
        pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(filenName);
        string path = filenName.Replace("/", "//");
        txtimgPath.Text = path;

    }


}
```